# reading some content from a web page read in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read some data from a python module from a web.

I manage to read, however having some difficulty in parsing this data and getting the required information.

My code is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 -tt

import urllib
import urllib2

def Connect2Web():
  aResp = urllib2.urlopen("https://uniservices1.uobgroup.com/secure/online_rates/gold_and_silver_prices.jsp");
  web_pg = aResp.read();

  print web_pg

#Define a main() function that prints a litte greeting
def main():
  Connect2Web()

# This is the standard boilerplate that calls the maun function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I print this [web page](https://uniservices1.uobgroup.com/secure/online_rates/gold_and_silver_prices.jsp) I get the whole web page printed.

I want to extract some information from it, (e.g. `"SILVER PASSBOOK ACCOUNT"` and get the rate from it), I am having some difficulties in parsing this html document.

Comment: Exactly what difficulties are you having?

Comment: i tried using "findall" method, however not sure, which parameters i should be taking???

Comment: re.findall(pattern, string[, flags])

meaning 
pattern=["SILVER PASSBOOK ACCOUNT"]
string=web_pg

Comment: it fails saying...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Work\Learn\Python\Web.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Work\Learn\Python\Web.py", line 23, in main
    Connect2Web()
  File "c:\Work\Learn\Python\Web.py", line 18, in Connect2Web
    matches = re.findall(["SILVER"],web_pg)
  File "c:\Program Files\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "c:\Program Files\Python27\lib\re.py", line 231, in _compile
    p = _cache.get(cachekey)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Please [edit] the question, and add the information there (in a nicely formatted way if possible).

Comment: @RikPoggi: Please check if this looks good now, done a bit of formatting.

Comment: I fixed your indentation (I'm not sure if I could). I'm not a license expert, but I think that by posting your code here it gets effectively released under CC-Wiki, so your copyright notice is ineffective. To re-phrase it: if the code you posted is copyrighted than there might be a license infringement.

Comment: @RikPoggi: Thanks for editing, however this is just the test message, which i have removed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to use regexps to get required data:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import re

def Connect2Web():
  aResp = urllib2.urlopen("https://uniservices1.uobgroup.com/secure/online_rates/gold_and_silver_prices.jsp");
  web_pg = aResp.read();

  pattern = "<td><b>SILVER PASSBOOK ACCOUNT</b></td>" + "<td>(.*)</td>" * 4
  m = re.search(pattern, web_pg)
  if m:
    print "SILVER PASSBOOK ACCOUNT:"
    print "\tCurrency:", m.group(1)
    print "\tUnit:", m.group(2)
    print "\tBank Sells:", m.group(3)
    print "\tBank Buys:", m.group(4)
  else:
    print "Nothing found"
```

Don't forget to `re.compile` the pattern if you are doing your matches in loop.

Answer (score 9):

It's not recommended to use RE to match XML/HTML. It can sometimes work, however. It's better to use an HTML parser and a DOM API.  Here's an example:

```
import html5lib
import urllib2

aResp = urllib2.urlopen("https://uniservices1.uobgroup.com/secure/online_rates/gold_and_silver_prices.jsp")
t = aResp.read()
dom = html5lib.parse(t, treebuilder="dom")
trlist = dom.getElementsByTagName("tr")
print trlist[-3].childNodes[1].firstChild.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

You could iterate over `trlist` to find your interesting data.

**Added from comment:** `html5lib` is third party module. See [html5lib site](https://github.com/html5lib/). The `easy_install` or `pip` program should be able to install it.

Comment: thanks Keith, however i am not able to compile the above, i am using Python 2.7.2, looks like not able to get "html5lib" module.
Which version of Python you are using please ???

Comment: @tush1r You need to install it. Make sure you have `easy_install`. If not, google `ez_setup`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that's a third party module. See [html5lib site](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/). The `easy_install` or `pip` program should be able to install it.

Comment: Seems like some mistype in d.getElementsByTagName("tr") - "d" is not defined.

Comment: Maybe he meant "dom", instead of "d"?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try [Grablib](http://grablib.org/).
And/or you can use XPath (with/without Grab). May be it will be usefull for you later, here some examples:

```
g = Grab()
g.go(address)

user_div = g.xpath('//*/div[@class="user_profile"]') # main <div> for parse
country = user_div.find('*/*/a[@class="country-name"]')
region  = user_div.find('*/*/a[@class="region"]')    # look for <a class="region">
city    = user_div.find('*/*/a[@class="city"]')

friends = [ i.text_content() for i in user_div.findall('dl[@class="friends_list"]/dd/ul/li/a[@rel="friend"]') ]

# and another ability, i.e. you have 2 tags: 
# <tr> <td>Text to grab</td> <td>if only that tag contains this text</td> </tr>

val = user_div.xpath(u"dl/dt[contains(text(),'%s')]/../dd/text()" % 'if only that tag contains this text')
# print val[0] <- will contain 'Text to grab'
```

Good luck.